# reverse voltage polarity protection

Tags: circuit-design, dc-dc-converter, buck, circuit-protection, pmos

I'm thinking about making a reverse polarity protection for a buck converter AOZ1284, and I've found this article [design-guide-pmos-mosfet-for-reverse-voltage-polarity-protection](https://components101.com/articles/design-guide-pmos-mosfet-for-reverse-voltage-polarity-protection)

I didn't find the spice model for AOZ1284 to simulate the full circuit.

My question : Can I use this circuit with the buck converter (I am working with 12V as input)

AOZ1284 [DataSheet](http://www.aosmd.com/res/data_sheets/AOZ1284PI.pdf)

[image]

Comment: what is the buck converter output voltage?

Comment: @jsotola the output voltage is 5V/4A

Comment: what happens if you use only a series diode?

Comment: @jsotola 
The series diode protection has a disadvantage, especially at low input voltages, due to the voltage drop across the diode. Depending on the choice of diode, a forward voltage drop of 0.2V to 0.7V can be expected, with an associated power loss = VF × IIN, which reduces both the conversion efficiency and the usable input voltage range. If the input current is 1A, then a standard power diode with VF = 0.5V dissipates 0.5W, equal to about a quarter of the dissipated power of a typical 15W converter, thus reducing the overall efficiency by 20%.